# Parse Date in PHP

Tags: php, date, parsing

I need some help parsing a date in PHP to a date object. I thought this was 8601 format, but `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, "2018-11-14T01:11:36.059Z")`  is not working.

Date Format is: 2018-11-14T01:11:36.059Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2018-11-14T01:11:36.059Z'));

//Output
2018-11-13 20:11:36
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! You saved me hours of time, as I don't write PHP very often

Comment: My pleasure .
You can learn more from php manual -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php